# Console on ESXi 5

Tags: vmware-esxi, console

Is there also a console on ESXi 5? The well known method from ESXi 4 for the "hiddenconsole" does not seem to work.

(Alt-F1, type "unsupported", enter root password)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In ESXi 5 (and 4.1), this is referred to as "Tech Support Mode."

It's an explicit option in the ESXi console interface.

See the [following article from VMWare on how to enter it](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1017910).